# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Username') while running sfdx force:package:version:list?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am getting following error

> Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Username')

while running sfdx force:package:version:list command?

I am using sfdx-cli/7.132.0 win32-x64 node-v16.13.1 Version.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug in the Salesforce platform+CLI that happens when you use the Free Limited Icense for your Dev Hub user - the license seems to have lost access to the User object, permissions wise, and this breaks all the various 2GP package commands.

We have had a Partner Case (#41792988). open for several weeks on this issue and are waiting for a positive outcome still. There is also a github issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1321

It seems that the problem may be a combination of CLI changes and platform changes. You may be able to work around the issue by downgrading the CLI.